# Getting <img src=""> attribute from AliExpress error

Tags: c#, html, image, webbrowser-control

Today I was trying to load images from aliexpress products.
I was using this code : `string NowImage = HJ.GetElementsByTagName("img")[0].GetAttribute("src");`

it worked for the first 8 images and didn't load the rest of images.
it was returning empty string.
And I checked the html of the aliexpress and found out that it should work.
Can someone help me ? Thanks for reading.

```
    public bool Search()
    {
        WB.DocumentCompleted += WB_SearchCompleted;
        WB.Navigate(URL);

        while (WB.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete)
            Application.DoEvents();
        return true;
    }
    private void WB_SearchCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        HtmlElementCollection HEC = WB.Document.GetElementsByTagName("li");

        foreach(HtmlElement HJ in HEC)
        {
            if(HJ.GetAttribute("qrdata") == "")
                continue;
            NowImage = HJ.GetElementsByTagName("img")[0].GetAttribute("src");
            //for the first 8 images it was loading perfect after that it was 
            //returning empty string
        }
    }
```

Comment: When you say *it should work*, what do you mean exactly ?

Comment: I mean that the attribute and the tagname are set correctly as this line of code is trying to access them.

Comment: Is there any error raised ? How many image should you get at the end of your process ?

Comment: number of images should be number of products on AliExpress products page. no errors it just return empty string

Comment: Could you please share your code so that we could help ?